# React, JS - Using forwardRef or state to set value inside nested child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

In my application, I have a chat screen which **maps** over chat messages and displays a **ChatMessage** component for each message, like so:

**Chat.js:**

```
 Object.values(chatMessages).map((messageObj, index) => {
    return <ChatMessage />
 })
```

**ChatMessage** component performs some logic, and then displays a **MessageBubble** component which renders the actual message.

**ChatMessage.js:**

```
// Perform some logic ...

return <MessageBubble  sentByUser={sentByUser} setReplyTo={setReplyTo} replyToMessageObj={replyToMessageObj} messageObj={messageObj}  isOwn={isOwn} />
```

Here is the code for **MessageBubble** which essentially just renders the message

```
// Performs some logic...

return <p>{messageObj.message}</p>
```

The problem I have is that I want to define a variable inside the **Chat** component, which holds the value of **one** of the `MessageBubble` components (Specifically a prop of the **MessageBubbleComponent**, e.g `ID`). Also note that any **ChatPage** could have dozens of **MessageBubble** components.

One solution I found was to define a **ref** inside **Chat.Js**, and then use `forwardRef` to pass the ref to **ChatMessage.js**, and then `forwardRef` again to pass the ref to `MessageBubble.js`. This would look like this:

**Chat.js:**

```
const ref = useRef(null)

 Object.values(chatMessages).map((messageObj, index) => {
    return <ChatMessage ref={ref}/>
 })
```

**ChatMessage.js:**

```
const ChatMessage = React.forwardRef(({messageObj}, ref) => {
     return <MessageBubble ref={ref} />
}))
```

**MessageBubble.js**:

```
const MessageBubble= React.forwardRef(({messageObj, prop}, ref) => {
     // Somewhere inside this component, use ref.current to update the value of the ref defined inside     
     Chat.js

     return <p>{messageObj.message} </p>
}))
```

Is this solution viable, or would this be a bad example of using **ref**. An alternative would be to store a `state` variable inside **Chat.js** and then pass `setStateVariable` as a **prop** to each **ChatMessage** and then to each **MessageBubble** component. Would `state` be a better use case for this problem, or would the use of `forwardRef` be acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: are you using Id in JSX of chat component?

Comment: @Anshu Only to store the ID in some sort of variable.i.e ref or state.

Comment: are you using `ref.current` during rendering of MessageBubble Component? Please update the problem and add how are you using ref.current? and how are you going to use ID in the chat? A brief description would be good.